# Trying to pass a Card object to an ArrayList

Tags: java

So I have a deck which is an array of card objects, I'm trying to take cards from that deck and "deal" them to players. When I try and pass the card to the player it gives me an error that I can't apply an Object. But in my player class I have an arrayList of Cards. What I don't understand is why its giving me the error when I'm adding the card object to an arrayList of card objects.

The error is in the dealCards method, this line "players[i].setHand(deck.get(cardCounter));", gives me the error.

```
public class War {

    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int numberOfPlayers;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 52;
    public static ArrayList<Card> mainDeck;
    public static Player[] players;
    public static int numberOfCardsDealt;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String playAgain;

        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the War Card Game!");
            System.out.print("Enter the number of players (2..6): ");
            numberOfPlayers = keyboard.nextInt();

            while (numberOfPlayers > 6 || numberOfPlayers < 2) {
                System.out.print("Enter the number of players (2..6): ");
                numberOfPlayers = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            players = createPlayers(numberOfPlayers);

            Deck deck = new Deck();
            deck.shuffleDeck();
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
                System.out.println(deck.getDeck().get(i).toString());
            }

            numberOfCardsDealt = mainDeck.size() / numberOfPlayers;
            players = dealCards(players, numberOfCardsDealt,deck.getDeck());

            System.out.println("Play again (y or n");
            playAgain = keyboard.next();
        } while(playAgain.charAt(0) == 'y');
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\tGoodbye");
    }

    public static Player[] dealCards(Player[] players,int numberOfCardsDealt,ArrayList deck) {
        int cardCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCardsDealt; j++) {
                players[i].setHand(deck.get(cardCounter));
            }
        }

        return players;
    }

public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Card> hand;
    private int score = 0;

    public Player() {hand = new ArrayList<>();}

    public void setHand(Card card) {
        hand.add(card);
    }

    public void setScore(int num) {
        score += num;
    }

    public int getScore() {return score;}

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {return hand;}

}

public class Deck {

    private Random rand = new Random();
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 52;
    ArrayList<Card> deck;

    public Deck() {

        deck = new ArrayList<>();

        //load cards with numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            deck.add(i,new Card(i));
            deck.get(i).setSuit(deck.get(i).getCardNumber() / 13);
            deck.get(i).setCardNumber(deck.get(i).getCardNumber() % 13);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getDeck() {return deck;}

    public void shuffleDeck() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    public int getMAX_SIZE() {return MAX_SIZE;}
}

public class Card {

    private int cardNumber;
    private String suit;

    public Card(int number) {
        cardNumber = number;
    }
    public Card(int number,String suit) {
        cardNumber = number;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        switch(suit){
            case 0: this.suit = "\u2660"; break; //Spades
            case 1: this.suit = "\u2665"; break; //Hearts
            case 2: this.suit = "\u2666"; break; //Diamonds
            case 3: this.suit = "\u2663"; break; //Clubs
            default: break;
        }
    }
    public void setCardNumber(int cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }
    public int getCardNumber() {return cardNumber;}

    public String getSuit() {return suit;}

    public String toString() {
        return cardNumber + suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us some more information - is this a compiler error, or a runtime exception? What line of code does it occur on? What is the full error message/stack trace?

Comment: The error is in the dealCards method. players[i].setHand(deck.get(cardCounter));